# filtering a Pandas DataFrame using dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with multiple columns and I would like to filter it to get a subset that matches certain values in different columns. I used the `isin()` method and passed a dictionary but I keep getting the `TypeError` with the message `TypeError: only list-like or dict-like objects are allowed to be passed to DataFrame.isin(), you passed a 'str'`.

Following is an example of the problem:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'surname':['wang','park','park'],'name':['tim','john','sam']})
display(x)

filt_dict = {'surname':'park'}

x[x.isin(filt_dict)]
```

I expected two rows where the `surname` matches `park`, but I get the `TypeError` instead.

What gives?

Comment: Could it have multiple entries the dict?

Comment: It's a little unclear how this should scale with multiple items in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

As you need to filter by dict values:

```
In [118]: x[x.surname.isin(filt_dict.values())]
Out[118]: 
  surname  name
1    park  john
2    park   sam
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build the mask with `np.logical_and` (`or`) + `reduce` depending if the condition is any row that satisfies all conditions or any row that satisfies any condition, respectively.

```
m = np.logical_and.reduce([x[k] == v for k,v in filt_dict.items()])
# np.logical_or.reduce if an `|` condition

x[m]
#  surname  name
#1    park  john
#2    park   sam
```

---

If you want to make it a bit safer to allow for multiple types of comparisons we can use `isin` when we pass an iterable (that's not a string) and equality checks otherwise.

```
m = np.logical_and.reduce(
        [x[k].isin(v) if (hasattr(v, '__iter__') and not isinstance(v, str)) 
         else x[k] == v for k,v in filt_dict.items()])
```

Answer (score 1):

The values of the filtering dict must be lists:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'surname': ['wang', 'park', 'park'], 'name': ['tim', 'john', 'sam']})

d = {'surname': ['park']}

print(x.isin(d))
```

**Output**

```
   surname   name
0    False  False
1     True  False
2     True  False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = [s for s in x.itertuples() if s.surname == filt_dict['surname']]
>>> x
[Pandas(Index=1, surname='park', name='john'), Pandas(Index=2, surname='park', name='sam')]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions are flexible. Based on your input, one is:

First, to eliminate the error message, the dict you input to `isin()` is supposed to be `{'surname':['park']}` other than `{'surname':'park'}`

Also, `x[x.isin(filt_dict)]` would not give you what you want because `x.isin(filt_dict)` return a dataframe other than a series. To fix it, add `['surname']`:

`x[x.isin(filt_dict)['surname']]`
or 
`x[x.isin(filt_dict)[[*filt_dict][0]]]`

---

output:

```
  surname  name
1    park  john
2    park   sam
```